# Segue not working on tableView

Tags: ios, action, segue

Okay, I got this strange situation.

I have multiple tableViews in my project, but only on one tableView I can click on an item and perform an action (go to next segue).

On the other tableViews I can click what I want but nothing happens. 
I removed the one that was working and made the link again, and it was still working. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Storyboard trying to show all the relevant tables/segues?

Comment: The answer down below solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest to you to use the delegate method to handle item selection:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // Here you can do something with, e.g. push a view controller:
  id vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

In most cases it is more comfortable to implement and maintain table views with delegates instead of using segues.

Comment: Actually your answer does not match the case. You're not pushing a segue but presenting a view controller programmatically. If you want to use this way, use `performSegueWithIdentifier:` instead.

Comment: Thanx, the combination of your answers worked for me!

Comment: I don't think that the answer to how to make a segue work should be "don't use segues".